# Android view.request focus

Tags: android

Despite, 
 i use xml codes:

```
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Or clear and request focus:

```
CountEdit1.clearFocus();
CountEdit1.requestFocus();
```

Or in java set focusable:

```
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
view.requestFocus();
```

Or use input manager:

```
InputMethodManager iMM = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
etv1.requestFocus()
iMM.showSoftInput(etv1, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

i didn't get any solution for show input window again(it just Works for first onclick). These are relative code snippet:

```
 imagearama.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("tago", "onclicktıklandı");
            InputMethodManager iMM = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            etv1.requestFocus();
            iMM.showSoftInput(etv1, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            editTextAyarla(etv1, imagesimge, logo, imagearama);
        }
    });
```

These are backpressed codes :

```
 View view = getCurrentFocus();
    InputMethodManager iMM = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    iMM.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    view.clearFocus();
```

I want that when user clicks "imagearama" button , input window be opened.(It just occurs first click)

Relative xml code snippet :

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/aramaalani"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textColor="#33ff33"
            android:background="#843221"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:hint="Aramak istedigini gir"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />
```

Comment: Can you try calling setSoftInputMode on the window? e.g  getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE)

Comment: sorry for wrong guidance , i just edited it.

Comment: No it just focus on first time